# predict function in R sommer v 4.1.1

Tags: r, mixed-models

In the newest version of the sommer package, some adaptations to the predict function have been made, unfortunately, I am having issues with it in the newest version.

if I do not specify any classify variable:

predict.mmer(modelh)
Error in strsplit(classify, ":") : non-character argument

predict.mmer(modelh, classify = "GEN")
Error in `[.data.frame`(object$dataOriginal, , c(colnames(DTX), ignored,  :
undefined columns selected

my model looks like this:

mmer(data = data, fixed = value ~ 1 ,
random = ~ GEN + ROWf + COLf + spl2D(ROW,COL),  rcov = ~vs(units))

further question: in the model above, I am getting all the same values in the model$fitted vector, which is equal to the intercept. As I understand, the fitted value should also include random effects like GEN, ROWf, ... . Am I misunderstanding something here?

Appreciate any advice,
Best Regards, Hermann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the 4.1.1 version the predict function is not used anymore to get fitted values, but to obtain adjusted means for an specific classify argument. Therefore, the classify argument cannot be skipped.

If you need fitted values now the fitted() function should return what you're looking for.

Now, the issue with using the classify must come from the use of the spl2D() function outside of the vs() function. You may want to download the newest version from GitHub (version 4.1.2) and try with:

```
mix <- mmer(data = data, fixed = value ~ 1 , random = ~ GEN + ROWf + COLf + vs(spl2D(ROW,COL)), rcov = ~vs(units))
```

and use:

```
pp=predict.mmer(modelh, classify = "GEN")
```

for adjusted means for all GEN in the model, that uses specific terms in the model for the averaging and classifying sets, and

```
ff=fitted.mmer(modelh)
```

if you want fitted values for the observations.

Cheers,
Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Eduardo, works perfectly with 4.1.2.

One more question though. I am wondering about the definitions of residuals. It seems as if mmer calculates residuals as "residuals = response - fixed", rather than "residuals = response - fixed - random" ignoring random effects, no matter if a call the residuals from the model frame or using the residuals function. Is there a misunderstanding on my side?

Cheers Hermann